# How to secure IIS Web Server

Tags: asp.net, windows-security

We have a web application which consists of an IIS web server which is on the internet, and a database server, which IIS accesses over a VPN link.

The problem we have is that we need to store the connectstring somewhere (which obviously can't be in the database).

I note that it is possible to encrypt web.config connect strings using aspnet_regiis :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Can anyone comment on how robust this is.  What we do not want is the database being hacked from the internet.

One thing which concerns me is the aspnet_regiis is used to decrypt and encrypt and is installed on the machine itself.  So if the machine was compromised and this exe was on there, discovering the passwords would not be that hard.

So assuming that this method of securing a password is not recommended, what other options do I have.

Note that in case it is relevant, IIS is running in the context of IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not encrypt your configuration files to prevent being hacked from the internet. IIS will never serve *.config files. You encrypt configuration files to hide the information therein from server administrators.

If a remote attacker has access to the server and can run arbitrary executables, all bets are off. There's nothing you can do to secure the server after that.

How to prevent the server from being accessed remotely is too broad to answer, check [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) for general hints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realise that II will not be serving *.config files.  I was concerned about anything gaining access to the machine and decrypting the files.  Perhaps my starting point should be preventing access to the machine in the first place.  Note config encryption does not stop admins seeing the cleartext. All they need to do is run the asp_net_regiis tool.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, give your app pool identity (in your case IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool) access to the SQL Server.

Then use integrated authentication instead of password and username in your connection string:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  We were proceeding on the basis that doing it that way would mean that anything which could impersonate that user account would have access to the SQL Server -, so we have discounted that option at the moment.

Comment: That's true, but on the other hand, anything with that user account would somehow be able to access the sql server credentials from your connection string.

Comment: Back on a more general level, many of the possible options for achieving this will hang together OK as long as the server is locked down properly from the internet.  That is except for backups made of the server.   It would seem a possibility that if a backup was obtained it could be analysed and reverse engineered if necessary to hack into the system.  What is best practise for defending against compromise via backups ?

Comment: The other question about this approach is whether you should actually be encrypting your server & database / connectstring anyway.  If you should then the problem is still left unsolved.